# UnityPlayerActivity oncreate errors

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to run very simple program which start with:

```
MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

But on the on create i get this error:

```
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578): Device fingerprint: samsung/GT-I9100/GT-I9100:4.1.2/JZO54K/I9100XWLSW:user/release-keys
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578): Caused by:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578):    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578):    at com.example.t.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)   
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load main: findLibrary returned null
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-02 09:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(32578):    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

I use compiler 1.6 and took the jar - classes.jar from the unity folder

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the manifest.
Come [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) and follow the instructions!